# Inflated query count in OOB query reports

Tags: 2013, reports

I am relatively new to SharePoint and am analyzing the search reports for our new enterprise search solution.  I am noticing that the query counts appear to be inflated.  A query is counted once for the initial query and again for each pagination.  An additional query is also counted when a user returns to the search results page after opening a result then clicking the back button.

I want to be sure that this is OOB behavior for these reports before I dig deeper.

Any thoughts or suggestions anyone could provide is much appreciated.  Thank you.